# iScroll firing links onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

My app is a knockout app that generates an `<ul>` from an array containing 100+ items wrapped inside an iScroll container. Each `<li>` has a knockout click handler to load that data in a larger view.

My problem is that onScroll / touchmove (iScroll) these links are being triggered and I really don't want them to be because every time you go to scroll up/down, the element that you click to initialise the scrolling appears in the larger view.

I've set up a fiddle with knockout stripped out for simplicity as the issue lies with iScroll Bubbling and not Knockout.

I've tried preventDefault & stopPropagation but with no luck.

Fiddle: (no KO) http://jsfiddle.net/SLeKL/1/

Comment: Are you using iScroll5? Check out the `tap` event which seems to be there to get around problems like yours: http://iscrolljs.com/

Comment: That sorted it, thanks! I completely overlooked that in the doc.